# Sql Server Ranking Value Not Changing Please Help

Tags: sql-server, mysql

How to convert this (MySQL Query) to SQL Server?

Or how to get a ranking value not changing while I'm using where in query:

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       score, 
       FIND_IN_SET( score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT score
                            ORDER BY score DESC ) FROM scores)
                  ) AS rank
FROM scores WHERE name = A;
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for the complex - and expensive - `FIND_IN_SET()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` solution. All you need is the [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, score, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS rank
FROM scores ;
```

---

If you want to add a `WHERE` clause, say `WHERE name = 'C'` and still get the rank(s) - among all rows of the table - you can use either a CTE or a derived table:

```
-- derived table
SELECT d.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
        id, name, score, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS rank
    FROM scores
  ) AS d
WHERE d.name = 'C' ; -- arbitrary `WHERE`

-- CTE
WITH d AS
  (
    SELECT 
        id, name, score, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS rank
    FROM scores
  )
SELECT d.*
FROM d
WHERE d.name = 'C' ; -- arbitrary `WHERE`
```

Comment: but its like counter didnt stack the rank

Comment: ? What do you mean?

Comment: i want it like if i query the name like

`name | Rank
A         |   1
B         |   2
C         |   3
`


if i search the name like C

the output is C | 3  still get the ranking

Comment: Sorry, still not clear. Edit the question, put sample data (in text format or even better INSERT statement) and the expected output). Do you want to add a `WHERE` clause, say `WHERE name = 'C'` and still get the rank (among all rows of the table)?

Comment: the output must be 

`C | 3`

he still get the rank not like

`C  | 1`

Comment: @JarwinGines: Consider providing a data sample to work with, with which you'd be able to demonstrate how this solution fails. From where I'm sitting, this answer's query (either variation) should do what you are requesting, but it's pointless to argue if I or ypercubeᵀᴹ or anyone else can't see/use the same data sample as you do.

Comment: the output must be C | 3 he still get the rank not like C | 1

This is Right i get C | 1 as a top 1 but C is on the Top 3

Comment: As AndriyM commented 4 months ago: *Consider providing a data sample to work with, with which you'd be able to demonstrate how this solution fails.*